# How to interact with an element of masterPage.cs from another asp page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am having difficulty to load a controller "asp:droopDownItem" from the "connexion.aspx" and my element "asp:droopDownItem" is in the "masterPage.cs". I can well fill my "asp:droopDownItem", but the problem is that once arrived on the homepage, **my "asp:droopDownItem" is empty** .... :-( 
Why? 
I used the code provided by Micrososft to interact with an element of the master page remotely without success .. 
Here is my code

```cs
ContentPlaceHolder menuActive;
DropDownList cbbx_dbUser;
menuActive = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("menuActive");
if (menuActive != null)
{
    cbbx_dbUser = (DropDownList)menuActive.FindControl("cmbx_dbListUser");
    if (cbbx_dbUser != null)
    {
         for (int a = 0; a < resultArmsUser.GetLength(0); a++)
         {
             cbbx_dbUser.Items.Add(new ListItem(resultArmsUser[a, 5], resultArmsUser[a, 5]));
         }
         cbbx_dbUser.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When are you trying to access your dropdownlist on your masterpage?

OnInit
PageLoad
PreRender

It might be the Page Life Cycle event model that causes your problems.

Depending on when your masterpage populates your dropdown, you might get an empty dropdownlist.

Comment: Yes that's exactly his! Have you a solution to this problem? please?

Comment: Thannnnks a lot's ^^ I have try implement this override and that right !!

Comment: @MehdiBugnard: Editing the answer is not meant for responses.  You can respond by editing your question or adding a comment.